# Excel VBA Error while pasting data to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am pasting below the piece of code which picks up only the visible rows and pastes it to a new sheet for some more processing. However when it tries to paste, it fails with the error that "Excel cannot complete the operation with the resources. Please close some programs or try later". Any alternative to this code? BTW, this is excel 2007.

```
Function createSummary()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets.Add().Name = "Summary"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Font.Bold = False

    Columns("A").Insert
```

Comment: I havent posted the whole code as its not doing anything much.

Comment: Do you know how to debug the code? If yes then can you tell us which line exactly is giving the error? Also any reason why you have it as `Function createSummary()` and not `Sub createSummary()` ?

Comment: I have not tried your code but I do not recall ever being able to do anything between the `Copy` and the `Paste`.  I certainly would not try adding and renaming a worksheet between them.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to do. Some of your code seems useless.

Comment: The macro fails at ActiveSheet.Paste. I debugged it line by line and thats where it fails. I will try @TonyDallimore 's suggestion.

Comment: The macro pastes some data, but when pasting the last row, it fails with the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your workbook it looks as though you are having some sort of memory issues.

You don't need to select cells to work with them.  Try something like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets.Add().[A1]
End With

With ActiveSheet
    .Name = "Summary"
    .UsedRange.Cells.Font.Bold = False
    .Columns("A").Insert
End With
```

Comment: @iDevelop - Thanks.  Rajiv, you will need to add error handling for the specialcells method and also check a sheet named summary doesnt already exist before executing.

Comment: Perfect! This works like a charm and I got away with the error. Many thanks @Reafidy